# HP Smart Array 641 w/ failed drive - will not recognize replacement?

Tags: raid, hp

Have an old HP ML370 G4 server, drive 1:3 failed and went offline. We swapped in a replacement drive (from an old server, same size, RPM, etc, but different brand). It is still showing the drive as failed. How do we get the controller to rebuild and/or accept that it's no longer a failed drive?

This is the config from the HP ACU CLI:

=> ctrl all show config

Smart Array 641 in Slot 1

array A (Parallel SCSI, Unused Space: 0 MB)

```
  logicaldrive 1 (546.9 GB, RAID 5, OK)

  physicaldrive 1:0   (port 1:id 0 , Parallel SCSI, 146.8 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 1:1   (port 1:id 1 , Parallel SCSI, 146.8 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 1:2   (port 1:id 2 , Parallel SCSI, 146.8 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 1:3   (port 1:id 3 , Parallel SCSI, ??? GB, Failed)
  physicaldrive 1:4   (port 1:id 4 , Parallel SCSI, 146.8 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 1:5   (port 1:id 5 , Parallel SCSI, 146.8 GB, OK, active spare)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"but different brand" - ahem, I think you've answered your own question - HP only support their own disks on their controllers - a disk may seem similar but unless it's on the same firmware no SmartArray will think about dealing with it. Sorry.

Comment: found it on HP: http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/12067_na/12067_na.html#Options

Comment: @Tanarri - sorry, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @Tanarri - I see it shows a list of supported drive models, thanks. Nothing like referencing a footnote to show it's an unsupported configuration to use another brand drive.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean the drive in the HP carrier is a different brand.  Do you know the drive is definitely OK?  Perhaps your SCSI backplane is playing up (seen this plenty of times on DL380s).  Finally, the firmware level on the drive might be too low, although you'll see this being mentioned during POST.  If this is the case, download the latest HP firmware ISO.

Comment: Yes, I put an IBM U320 10K 146.8GB drive in the HP sled. Same speed, capacity, etc as the HP drive that was removed. It does spin the drive up upon inserting it, and flashes the array, but then continues to list the drive as "Failed".

Comment: Ah.  HP ship their carriers with various brands of disk.  I'm no microcode expert, but without running the HP firmware CD, the disk won't even have the HP code on it, and I don't know if HP check the model of the disk before allowing the firmware flash to work.  Like I said above, I've seen genuine HP U320 / SAS disks not work with a Smart Array controller, until the disk itself is brought up-to-date.